# tuning regularization parameter in backpropagation, by using backpropagation

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks, gradient-descent, regularization

When doing regularization in neural network backpropagation you have to set a reasonable value for the regularization parameter (e.g. if doing L2 regularization). I'm used to: 1. people either just setting the value constant at somewhat resonable value based on what other people say and not actually tuning it, or 2. saying that you could tune the hyperparameter using crossvalidation by doing a grid search on that parameter space and taking the argmin.

But then I read somewhere that you could tune the regularization parameter at the same time in backpropagation by calculate the gradient of the cost wrt the regularization parameter, just like any weight? But wouldn't tuning this way always drive the regularization parameter to 0 because for any positive value of the reg. parameter, it  will increase the cost function (since if using L2 or L1 norm regularization the term for the weights wil always be positive)?

Comment: You didn't define the regularization parameter.. Do you mean the $\lambda > 0$ in $J(w) = \sum_i d (f(x_i),y_i)+ \lambda \|w\|^2$ where $J$ is the criterion to be minimized, $x_i$ the $i$-th input, $y_i$ the wanted output, $f(x_i)$ the output given by the neural network, $d$ a distance function, $w$ the weights of our neural network to be optimized ?

Comment: Note $t \mapsto \tanh(\omega t)$ is smooth for $\omega$ small but for $\omega$ large it is almost discontinuous. Thus a large $\lambda$ favors smoothness. If $\omega$ is very small then $\tanh(\omega t)$ is almost linear, so a very large $\lambda$ favors linearity.

Comment: Thanks, Yes like you said, I mean lambda as you described it, the regularization parameter multiplied on some Lp norm of the weights. So I'm still not clear if this is a legit way to tune lambda?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you would backpropagate only the error term for purposes of calculating the loss w.r.t. lambda, so that lambda will go up if larger weights would lead to higher error, etc. The weights themselves would still be shrunk as usual.

Comment: @dektorpan: Where did you read about this approach?